# How to get rid of dust mite effectively?

Tags: health, sleeping, dust

What I tried:

- Gave the cats away
- I bought a powerful vacuum cleaner
- I bought an air purifier
- Regularly wash surfaces

It helps, but not for long. Any tips?

Comment: You may operate under a misconception. The chances that you can eliminate all dust mites forever are pretty much zero. “Doesn’t help for long”’is exactly what is to be expected, regular cleaning (to remove the allergens) and making their environment reasonably inhospitable (to reduce reproduction rates) is the only quasi-permanent solution I know of.

Answer (score 2):

Dust mites are ubiquitous, and there are even mites ([Demodex genus](https://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/what-are-demodex-mites)) in most people's skin pores -- perfectly normal, and nothing to worry about.

That said, if cleaning isn't sufficient to reduce dust mites to a level that doesn't bother you, i.e., they cause allergic reactions, consult a doctor for help.

However, I *do* find some tasks, e.g., emptying a vacuum cleaner bag, releases an annoying cloud of dust and the accompanying mites. Try to do such tasks outdoors, and change clothes and wash hands, arms and face if particularly sensitive. In extreme cases, use a filter mask and disposable gloves.

Answer (score 2):

My daughter has a dust mite allergy, so we had to do this. Here's what worked for her room:

1. Wash bed linens in hot water and let them get some sunlight when possible.
2. Use a pillow cover that is impervious to dust mites.
3. Use a HEPA filter for your home's air conditioner / furnace / fan.
4. Use a vacuum cleaner that filters its exhaust well. HEPA is good here too.
5. Ventilate rooms often, either by opening windows or using central air.
6. Use microfiber clothes for dusting. They gather more of it, and easily wash for reuse.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the mites that are the problem, it's their droppings, which dry and form microscopic dust particles.

And that isn't their fault; it's a result of feeding them too much.
What they like to eat is dead skin cells.
(Most of the "dust" one sees in a house is actually shed human skin.)
So while getting rid of the cats was a good start, you really need to get rid of all the people too.

That's usually not practical, so the best you can do is to dust all surfaces and vacuum all floors, as often as possible; whatever you can do to eliminate their food supply.
Removing carpeted flooring will help a lot too.

This page has other helpful suggestions:

> … Dust mites are very small, insect-like pests that feed on dead human skin cells and thrive in warm, humid settings.
> … people who are allergic to dust or dust mites are reacting to inhaling proteins in dust that comes from dust mite feces, urine or decaying bodies.
> …
>
> Dust mites can live in the bedding, mattresses, upholstered furniture, carpets or curtains in your home. Dust mites are nearly everywhere; roughly four out of five homes in the United States have dust mite allergens in at least one bed.
>
> — [Dust Mites | American Lung Association](https://www.lung.org/clean-air/at-home/indoor-air-pollutants/dust-mites)